# How math-oriented can questions on the site be?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

This is something I'm somewhat unclear about. Can we, for example, ask puzzles that require the use of calculus to solve? What about more sophisticated mathematical methods? Or should such questions be reserved for Math.SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why using advanced mathematics would disqualify any questions. Not every user has to understand every question and answer.  In fact, I think some of the more enlightening answers about probabilities and distributions of puzzle types will require such advanced mathematics.

Comment: I agree, but I also think that if a question can also be answered in a way that is easier to understand, it would be helpful to add that explanation as well. Not every user has to understand every question and answer, absolutely--but if we *can* get more people to understand, I feel like we should try :) +1!