# Can the maths problem close vote be objective?

Tags: discussion

[It's come up before on meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/revisiting-the-math-question-or-math-puzzle-policy), [a lot](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/should-we-disable-the-math-problem-close-reason), it seems.

However, I don't know whether there's a set of specific rules that define what is a maths problem and what isn't one.

For example:

> Question *x* is a objectively a maths problem, if:
>
> - *a*
> - *b*
> - *c*
>
> *etc.*

Answer (score 4):

You are asking, "When is something a math problem, and therefore not a puzzle?" I would argue the following:

> Every math question is a puzzle, even textbook ones. They're just really bad puzzles.

The reason I say this is because math problems fit the pattern that a lot of valid puzzles have. You start with some initial state, there are a certain number of allowed "steps" you can take, and the goal is to reach an end state. 
For example, for solving the equation $\frac{8x+3}7=5x+2$, the steps you would use are adding or multiplying both sides by a number, and the goal is an equation of the form $x=\_$. This paradigm, of starting state, allowed steps, goal, is shared by rubiks cubes, chess puzzles, lights out, sokoban, mazes,  peg solitaire, and so on and so on.

Why is the puzzle bad? Because for us, it's easy to find the path from start to goal; we're used to the steps, as we've been doing them since middle school. It's a rote problem for us, but for those just learning algebra, it's challenging, as they aren't comfortable with the steps yet. For some people, $\frac{8x+3}7=5x+2$ is a genuine challenge, and requires a bit of cleverness to navigate the unfamiliar maze of allowed algebraic operations. For that reason, you can't objectively say that it is not a puzzle; you can only subjectively say that you don't find it interesting.

By saying that a math problem must have a "clever or elegant solution" or "unexpected result," you tread on thin ice. These terms are subjective, not only from person to person, but also form era to era. Consider the question

> What is the area under the parabola $y=x^2$ and between the lines $x=0$, $x=1$, $y=0$?

Nowadays, this problem is rote and uninteresting, easily solved by anyone taking Calc 1. But, in 1635, this problem was much more challenging for Cavalieri, requiring the ingenuity to approximate the area by smaller and smaller rectangles, and further to exactly compute these approximating sums using the non-obvious identity $1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$. Certainly, this problem is interesting, the solution is clever, and the simplicity of the area being just $1/3$ is surprising. But those descriptions aren't true anymore, because we've thought about similar problems over and over in the unpleasant setting of calculus homework.

In my mind, something that was a puzzle yesterday should still be one today, even if our opinion of it has changed. Therefore, the concepts of "surprising" and "elegant," which are destroyed when the same puzzle is considered over and over, can't be included the definition of a math puzzle.

Comment: Could you name examples of maths puzzles that aren't maths problems?

Comment: @TheBitByte There is an island with 13 red, 15 blue, and 17 green chameleons. When two differently colored chameleons meet, they change to the third color. Is it possible for all chameleons to become the same color?

Comment: What makes this a puzzle rather than a maths problem? What is the exact definition of "maths puzzle" that excludes maths problems?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really think of a good answer. I think all math problems are puzzles, but I'm not sure what to think about the other way around.

Comment: If all maths problems are puzzles, they don't all have to be *good* puzzles, though. However, what is "good" and what isn't, that is not an objective classification.

Comment: @TheBitByte I agree, it is not objective at all. You asked for an objective set of rules, and I don't think I can give any. Maybe none exist?

Comment: Well, I think this close reason needs to be removed until we get a clear set of rules about it. @Deusovi, what do you think?

Comment: @TheBitByte No, the point of having humans apply a close reason is that we can collectively decide—when presented with a new post—what *is* and *isn't* a puzzle.  There's nothing wrong with having subjectivity here.  Mike (and rand in his answer) have done a good job listing some general criteria. If enough Puzzling users of > 3000 rep think it looks like a math problem and not a puzzle, then that's what matters.  An OP can always argue/explain/edit to make his/her case, but having 100% clarity in close reasons isn't realistic.  How would one ever 100% define what is "too broad"?

Comment: @DanRussell Yes, good general criteria, just too broad. It needs to be refined a bit. Subjective thinking is fine, but you need a clear set of rules to supplement that.

Answer (score 3):

From [the canonical meta post on maths problems vs maths puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373) (which is linked to from every single question closed for this reason):

> So, what makes something a math[s] puzzle rather than math[s] problem? I think there's a few features.
>
> - Clever or elegant solution, often an "aha" moment
> - Unexpected problem statement.
> - Unexpected or counterintuitive result.
>
> [...]
>
> In contrast, math[s] problems tend to be "textbook". And by that I don't mean that they have to come from textbooks (or that textbooks can't contain math[s] puzzles), but that they use standard, staightforward methods than anyone familiar with the subject is expected to know. They can be difficult, but their goal is to test comprehension of the material, not ingenuity. This doesn't apply to problems from math[s] olympiads like the Putnam exam, which are designed to have clever solution[s].

Comment: @TheBitByte It's nearly impossible for any close reason to be 100% objective. That's why the closing of questions is handled by human beings rather than an automatic algorithm. Is there an objective criterion for "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based"? There will always be some level of subjectivity, and borderline cases.

Comment: @TheBitByte: PPCG still has edge cases that they handle with close votes.

Comment: My vote of disapproval is part of my ongoing disagreement with the singling out of mathematics as a close reason.

Answer (score 0):

[My answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4939/11876) in the second link you gave is objective and seemed to be acceptable to a majority of voters.

> A math *puzzle* must:
>
> - be more than plain calculation
> - not require heavy calculation (unless tagged [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle))
>
> and most importantly,
>
> - require some *insight* that makes the problem easier to solve

Comment: Gotta say I disagree with the first of these bullet points - and judging from the comments on that answer, so do many others. I [once posted](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20327/the-magic-of-the-primes) a very nice and interesting puzzle (well, IMO, anyway - that's why I posted it, after all!) which required the Green-Tao theorem to solve.

Comment: What is "plain calculation"? Addition and subtraction, etc, only? Or is square root allowed? What about factorials?

Comment: @TheBitByte: Anything that can be solved with a simple algorithm.

Comment: What is a "simple algorithm"? Are factorials simple? Is a square root simple and a cube root or above not simple?

Comment: @TheBitByte: Okay, let me rephrase that. Anything that can be solved purely with an algorithm is not a puzzle. So "calculate √10" is not a puzzle, even if you replace the square root with a cube root.

Comment: As an example, "add 2+2" is technically an algorithm. You haven't defined the scope of the algorithms you're talking about

Comment: @TheBitByte: Yes! It is! Which is why that's not a puzzle. Look, the close reasons are slightly subjective *by design*. It's so we don't *have* to have long, tedious conversations clarifying every minutia of the rules.

Comment: My vote of disapproval is part of my ongoing disagreement with the singling out of mathematics as a close reason.

Comment: @Deusovi, "which is why is not a puzzle" <--- that doesn't mean all algorithms are not allowed, though.

Comment: @humn: We [talked about this already](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/should-we-disable-the-math-problem-close-reason#comment10515_4939).

Comment: And chatted, which I appreciate (very much!), but still disagree that mathematics should have a special status.

Comment: @humn: If we had people regularly asking us to analyze poetry or battles of WWII, then we would also have close reasons for literature and history.

Comment: @Deusovi http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/should-we-disable-the-math-problem-close-reason#comment10521_4939

Comment: @TheBitByte: I've removed that part of the close reason.

Comment: @randal'thor: Fair enough! I took that part out.

Comment: @Deusovi Good. You still need to define what "simple calculation" exactly is, though.

Comment: @TheBitByte: I already have. Anything that can be done purely by an algorithm.

Comment: @Deusovi, Again, what *kind* of algorithm? The word "algorithm" encompasses lots of different stuff, you could potentially be banning tons of questions here just because they're "algorithms" This brings us back to the main problem, if you had said "simple algorithms are not allowed, but other ones are", the word "simple" is subjective, if you're a professional mathematician a university textbook problem might be simple, but an eighth grader couldn't solve such a "simple" question.